# How to parse json data which comes from kafka topic in Storm scheme class?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm getting the json data from the kafka topic.
How can i apply json parsing to get all the fields for all the objects in storm scheme class which uses De-serialization method after that i'm returning the values to new return Values().(backtype.storm.tuple.Values class method) ?i.e, if i have 2 json objects in my topic i loop them to get the all the fields, at last i have to return all the values to the return method.my return should contain all the fields of two json objects.

My problem:
only the 2 obj json data is returned in the return method.
i think all the fields of 2nd object is overriding the 1st object fields.Finally second object fields are returned at end.

can any one of you give me an idea to return all the objects fields(1,2 objects fields )....

Thanks in Advance

```
public class MainParserSpout implements Scheme{
  String tweet_created_at;
  String tweet_id;
  String tweet_id_str;
  String tweet_text;
  String tweet_source;`    
@Override

try{

public List<Object> deserialize(byte[] bytes){
  String twitterEvent = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
   JSONArray JSON = new JSONArray(twitterEvent);
      for(int i=0;i<JSON.length();i++) {
        JSONObject object_tweet=JSON.getJSONObject(i);
//Tweet status                  
          try{
            this.tweet_created_at=object_tweet.getString("created_at");
            this.tweet_id=object_tweet.getString("id");
            this.tweet_id_str=object_tweet.getString("id_str");
            this.tweet_text=object_tweet.getString("text");
            this.tweet_source=object_tweet.getString("source");
          }catch(Exception e){}
    } //array for close
}catch(Exception e){}
} //JSON array close
  return new Values(tweet_created_at,tweet_id,tweet_id_str,tweet_text,tweet_source);
} //deserialize method close
public Fields getOutputFields() {
    return newFields("tweet_created_at","tweet_id","tweet_id_str","tweet_text","tweet_source");
} //getOutputFields method close
} //class close
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do... Can you give a small example showing the two JSON objects and the expected output tuple(s) you want to get?

Comment: i added the code example.if my tweet object contains two tweets only 2nd tweet fields i.,e: tweet_created_at,id.text,source of the second tweet is returned at last .please share an idea how to return the values for the each iteration @Matthias J. Sax

Comment: Your code example seems to be incomplete... Furthermore, `deserialize` must return a single tuple. Thus, all data from your JSON must be collected into a single return value. You cannot return multiple tuples from a single tweet.

Comment: yeah ! can't we try for a getting multiple tuples . I want the way to get multiple tuples values,can name out any other class in storm package that may help me solve this problem.I'm reading the data from the kafak topic.So I used the deserialize method.@ Matthias J. Sax

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "multiple tuples values" -- a tuple has multiple values... Using `deserialize` is the right way to go; however, you cannot get multiple tuples in a single call. However, you could emit two tweets by "doubling" your tuple, ie, having each value/field/attribute twice. Afterwards, you could use a bolt, that takes a "double-tweets", splits this tuple and emit two single-tweet-tuples.

Comment: yeah good idea thank you ! i have an idea of using append with comma to each iteration and store the values each iteration in one tuple object itself,while I’m storing it . I will make use of regex i will split them. @ Matthias J. Sax

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get multiple tuples in a single call of `deserialize`. However, you could emit two tweets by "doubling" your tuple, ie, having each value/field/attribute twice. Afterwards, you could use a bolt, that takes a "double-tweets", splits this tuple and emit two single-tweet-tuples.

Something like (I am not familiar with the JSON Tweet format, so this a more a guess with regard to the code example form the question):

```java
@Override
public List<Object> deserialize(byte[] bytes){
  List<String> doubleTweet = new ArrayList<String>();

  try{
    String twitterEvent = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    JSONArray JSON = new JSONArray(twitterEvent);


    for(int i=0;i<JSON.length();i++) {
      JSONObject object_tweet=JSON.getJSONObject(i);
      for(int j=0;j<object_tweet.length();j++){
        //Tweet status                  
        try{
          doubleTweet.add(object_tweet.getString("created_at"));
          doubleTweet.add(object_tweet.getString("id"));
          doubleTweet.add(object_tweet.getString("id_str"));
          doubleTweet.add(object_tweet.getString("text"));
          doubleTweet.add(object_tweet.getString("source"));
        }catch(Exception e){}
      }
    }
  }catch(Exception e){}

  return doubleTweet;
}
```

`doubleTweet` contains each field twice (fields 0-4 for the first tweet and field 5-9 for the second tweet). Thus, a consecutive bolt can just extract those fields an emit a 5-field tuple for each tweet).

As an alternative, you could also use `RawScheme` and do the JSON parsing in a follow up bolt. In this bolt, you can emit multiple tuples (ie, one for each tweet): https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka#multischeme

If you use `RawScheme` a tuple with a single `byte[]` field is emitted by the spout. Thus, you can do the JSON parson just in `Bolt.execute()` and call `Collector.emit()` for each Tweet.

Comment: can you give me a code example for"doubling" and  "RawScheme"?@Matthias J. Sax

Comment: do I need to return  list object "doubleTweet" to return newFields()? done a small correction in the question please have a took at it @Matthias J. Sax

Comment: when I returned the list object to the new feilds(); I'm getting the following error as follow Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tuple created with wrong number of fields. Expected 1 fields but got 5 fields.@Matthias J. Sax

Comment: I never work with Kafka and Schema by myself. Not sure, why it expects one Field instead of five. Can you add the Stacktrace to your question? And the code that assembles the topology?

Answer (score 1):

I missed the point that kafka is message publish-subscribe messaging system.
when I tried to send the data to producer I'm sending the a Json chuck 20 objects as a single message but my scheme works for single Json chuck only.So I divided that single 20 objects Json chuck into 20 json chucks and sent the each chuck to Json producer.